# Apache Spark のデバックに関してIntelliJを利用しているのですが、毎回エラーが発生します

Tags: java, apache, scala, spark

私は apache spark にコミットしてまだ日が浅いのですが、最近 example module から spark object (spark LR) のデバックをしたところエラーが発生してしまいました。
具体的には、以下のメッセージが表示されます。

```
C:\Users\frpgm\IdeaProject\junichi\common\sketch\src\main\java\org\apache\spark\util\sketch\Murmur3_x86_32.java
Error:(69, 22) java: シンボルを見つけられません
  シンボル:   変数 Platform
  場所: クラス org.apache.spark.util.sketch.Murmur3_x86_32
C:\Users\frpgm\IdeaProject\junichi\common\sketch\src\main\java\org\apache\spark\util\sketch\CountMinSketchImpl.java
Error:(220, 51) java: シンボルを見つけられません
  シンボル:   変数 Platform
  場所: クラス org.apache.spark.util.sketch.CountMinSketchImpl
Error:(221, 51) java: シンボルを見つけられません
  シンボル:   変数 Platform
  場所: クラス org.apache.spark.util.sketch.CountMinSketchImpl
C:\Users\frpgm\IdeaProject\junichi\common\sketch\src\main\java\org\apache\spark\util\sketch\BloomFilterImpl.java
Error:(87, 51) java: シンボルを見つけられません
  シンボル:   変数 Platform
  場所: クラス org.apache.spark.util.sketch.BloomFilterImpl
Error:(88, 51) java: シンボルを見つけられません
  シンボル:   変数 Platform
  場所: クラス org.apache.spark.util.sketch.BloomFilterImpl
Error:(110, 51) java: シンボルを見つけられません
  シンボル:   変数 Platform
  場所: クラス org.apache.spark.util.sketch.BloomFilterImpl
Error:(111, 51) java: シンボルを見つけられません
  シンボル:   変数 Platform
  場所: クラス org.apache.spark.util.sketch.BloomFilterImpl
```

可能であれば、run/debug configuration の設定まで教えてもらえるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 1):

> C:\Users\frpgm\IdeaProject\junichi\common\sketch\src\main\java\org\apache\spark\util\sketch\Murmur3_x86_32.java
>   Error:(69, 22) java: シンボルを見つけられません
>     シンボル:   変数 Platform
>     場所: クラス org.apache.spark.util.sketch.Murmur3_x86_32

最初のエラーは、ソースコードでは以下の行です（他のエラーも同じですが）。

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/common/sketch/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/util/sketch/Murmur3_x86_32.java#L69

簡単にいうと、ソースコードをビルド（コンパイル）できていません。`Platform`といのは、`Murmur3_x86_32`というクラスと同じパッケージにあるクラス`Platform`のことです。このクラスのclassファイルか、それを含むjarファイルが見つけられていません。

Qiitaにご要望の記事が掲載されているようです。他にもいろいろなブログで紹介されているようでしたが、どれかを参考に最初からやり直した方が早いかもしれませんね。

**Apache SparkのソースファイルをIntelliJでデバッグする**
https://qiita.com/iyunoriue/items/66a563dce56afd130dab

**Scala + Apache Spark をIntelliJにて開発する方法**
https://qiita.com/yk-tanigawa/items/4fc86c7e0e529c3b2fa0